# jquery if each true

Tags: jquery, validation, if-statement, each

So, in a form I have multiple choice and therefore an array of answers that I need validate. My attempt at the code is this, but it just returns that 'i' (from the .each() line) is not defined:

```
function validTextAnswers(i, answer){
    var answer = $j(this) 
    // ^ may not be needed, but I was using it 
    // when I was not passing arguements
    if( (answer.val()=="") || (textAnswers.val()==null )){
        alert('Note: Please fill in all answers.'),
        answer.focus()
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}

function validQuizCreate(){
    var course = $j('#course-selection .selected')
    var question = $j('textarea[name="question"]')
    var textAnswers = $j('div.answer:visible').children('input[type="text"]');

    if( (question.val()=="") || (question.val()==null) ){
        alert('You have to supply a question.'),
        question.focus()
        return false;
    }

if( !textAnswers.each(validTextAnswers(i, answer)) ){
    console.log('all seems good!')
    return false
}
```

I've played around with the code quite a bit just it's just breaking jQuery when I do.
(Note: Assume $ for $j, it's to avoid collisions with prototype on another section of the site.)

**Solution**:

```
// jQuery filter() can be used for this:
var validTextAnswers = textAnswers.filter(function(){
        return this.value != '';
    }).length == '4'; // four because the test is A though D.

// If all 4 multiple choice answers are not empty, it returns true.

// so to use it I can say:
    if(!validTextAnswers){
        alert('Please fill in all multiple choice options.')
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you be a bit more specific about what "breaking jQuery" means? When is this code run?

Comment: `if( !textAnswers.each(validTextAnswers(i, answer)) )` a function call that doesn't return a function for a parameter that expects a function won't work out very well.

Comment: `$.each` is not the right function for that problem. It will always return a jQuery object which evaluates to true. You want something like `Array#every`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every.

Comment: And +1 to Felix, `if( !textAnswers.each(validTextAnswers) )` wouldn't work as well as `$.each` returns an object.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome Andrew! By breaking jQuery I meant that in the firebug console I'm getting errors from the jQuery file (on line 2). Felix thank you for the upkeep on this post. I appreciate your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`each` returns a jQuery object which is always a "truethy" value.

You can use `filter`:

```
var isValid = textAnswers.filter(function() {
    return this.value == "invalild"
}).length > 0;

if (!isValid) {
    alert('PROBLEM!!!');
}​
```

Comment: I see, this is a tricky way of validating, but it works. I'm going to get .length before filter and after filter (testing for valid input) and then compare. Thanks for pointing me to .filter(), I just read up on it on jQuery docs :)

Comment: Ps, I advocate console.log() over alert() for testing, but you are correct to say alert to reflect my code.

Answer (score -3):

`each` takes a function argument, you are calling the function and passing its return value.

Consult the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/) on `each()` for proper usage.

Comment: Correct, but `$.each` is not the right function for this problem anyway.